# Press OK on cleanmgr dialog

Tags: windows, batch

I'm trying to do disk cleanup using batch file without any user interaction and encounter this problem.
After running `cleanmgr.exe /verylowdisk /d c`, there's a dialog window where I currently have to press OK button manually to proceed to the next command on the batch file.
Is there a way to press the button automatically after the dialog pop out?
As the dialog is part of `cleanmgr` and would not terminate until I click the OK button, I cannot call another function to press the button.

Comment: Use the `/sageset:n` commandline switch. See [Automate Enhanced Disk Cleanup Tool operation in Windows 10/8/7](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/automate-disk-cleanup-utility-windows)

Comment: @DavidPostill why is this not posted as an answer?

Comment: @DoktorJ Because at the time, I didn't have time ... and it's not clear which value of `n` the OP requires to solve his issue.

Comment: `n` is an arbitrary value. As long as you use the same `n` for sageset (when creating the settings you want to use) and sagerun (when executing cleanup) you should be set.

Answer (score 0):

Disk Cleanup (cleanmgr.exe) has a set of poorly-documented command line switches that are [decently written up by a third party here](https://winaero.com/blog/cleanmgr-exe-command-line-arguments-in-windows-10/). You likely want the `/SAGESET` and `/SAGERUN` switches.

First, run the following command *with elevated privileges* (admin):

```
cleanmgr.exe /SAGESET:n
```

(where `n` is any arbitrary number from 0-9999 of your choice -- see note 1 at end). This will open a dialog similar to the standard "Clean up system files" dialog of Disk Cleanup. Set the options you wish, and click OK. Your settings will be saved in the following registry folder:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VolumeCaches
```

You can then export that key (if necessary, to use on other machines) and import it on the machine you wish to run; see note 2 at the end for more details.

Now, once you have a system that has these settings saved on it, you can execute Disk Cleanup using those presets by calling

```
cleanmgr.exe /SAGERUN:n
```

Where `n` is the same number you used with the `/SAGESET` switch. This should run Disk Cleanup with the preset settings automatically, and it will close after it finishes running.

#### Notes

1. The site I linked says 0-65535, as do [this Microsoft TechNet article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/253597/automating-disk-cleanup-tool-in-windows) and [this Microsoft Support page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/253597/automating-disk-cleanup-tool-in-windows), but on the system I tested, values above 9999 truncated the least-significant digit, and `65500` indeed overwrote `6550` in my tests.
2. If you need to recreate the registry keys programmatically, look through each subkey in `VolumeCaches` for `StateFlagsNNNN` (where `NNNN` is your `n` value, zero-padded to four digits). You can then recreate the keys using a command such as

   ```
   reg.exe add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VolumeCaches\Setup Log Files" /v "StateFlags6550" /t REG_DWORD /d 2 /f
   ```

   This requires elevated privileges of course. Be sure to include *all* StateFlagsNNNN values even if they're zero, as omitting a key may result in undefined and possibly undesirable behavior.

Comment: @DavidPostill hope you don't mind :)